# Bad Performance Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing, task

I have a Parallel ForEach loop, that perform terrible. I don't understand what is wrong with the code that cause it to perform so bad, it runs for like 15 minutes, and I stop it.. I'm not sure if that some kind of memory leak or something similar, but the sequence version that I had before trying to change it to parallel, was working fine with the same base code.

Note that `sourceFileRead` and `outboundFileRead` are two big list of around 100,000 `IrfRecord`. That's why I wanted to move it to work in parallel, but it seems like i'm doing something very wrong ?

```
private async Task Compare(ConcurrentBag<IrfRecord> sourceFileRead, ConcurrentBag<IrfRecord> outboundFileRead)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
            Parallel.ForEach(sourceFileRead, (src) =>
            {

                var matched = outboundFileRead.FirstOrDefault(ob => ob.Key == src.Key);
                if (matched == null)
                {
                    ReportMissing(src.Key);
                    return;
                }
                CompareEntities(src, matched);
            });
        });


private void CompareEntities(IrfRecord src, IrfRecord matched)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < src.Body.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (src.Body[i].Settings.ToIgnore) continue;
            if (src.Body[i].Value != matched.Body[i].Value)
            {
                ReportDiff(src.Body[i], matched.Body[i], src.Key);
            }
        }
    }

private void ReportMissing(string srcKey)
    {
        _differencesCount.AddOrUpdate("Missing", new List<string> { srcKey },
            (key, existingVal) =>
            {
                existingVal.Add(srcKey);
                return existingVal;
            });
    }

private void ReportDiff(IrfRecordProperty srcProp, IrfRecordProperty obProp, string srcKey)
{
                _differencesCount.AddOrUpdate(srcProp.Settings.Name, new List<string> { srcKey + $@"  LC Value: {srcProp.Value}, D Value: {obProp.Value}" },
                    (key, existingVal) =>
                    {
                        existingVal.Add(srcKey + $@"  LC Value: {srcProp.Value}, D Value: {obProp.Value}");
                        return existingVal;
                    });
}
```

Am I using the Parallel.ForEach in a wrong way ?

Comment: How long does a non-parallelized version take?

Comment: _differencesCount.AddOrUpdate() is probably not thread-safe. And I don't see any SaveChanges() , is this EF?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight about 8-9 minutes

Comment: @HenkHolterman _differencesCount is just a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: When each list contains about 100k items, you do a lot of lookups on `outboundFileRead` in `var matched = outboundFileRead.FirstOrDefault(ob => ob.Key == src.Key);`. Can't you make it a dictionary with `IrfRecord.Key` as the Key? Also, why are `sourceFileRead` and `outboundFileRead` concurrent collections anyway, the seem only being read?

Comment: @PeterBons It was Dictionary in the beginning, but I had to move it into a object, it need to be complex type, than just a key-value pair. sourceFileRead and outboundFileRead are list I add to in difference piece of code, the code here is just a piece of the code that i compare them ..

Comment: "but I had to move it into a object, it need to be complex type, than just a key-value pair" -> Why not use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, IrfRecord>` (TKey being the type of IrfRecord.Key)? Should be faster for lookups. Anyway, try using a profiler to detect where most time is spend.

Comment: @PeterBons yes, that make sense.. I might make some modifications about that..